# Moving an object along a path ontouch

Tags: android, path, geometry

I have a stroke circle path and a little fill circle path and i want to move the little circle along the stroke circle path with touch, the little circle should not be outside the stroke circle. How can i do this ? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your touch might be slighty outside of your circle path. To provide object position at the circle, you can make the next:

```
    find position of touch against circle center
dx = touch.x - center.x
dy = touch.y - center.y
    find distance from the center
dist = sqrt(dx*dx +dy*dy)
     make new position at the same disraction form center but at circle radius distance
newx = center.x + radius * dx / dist
newy = center.y + radius * dy / dist
```